# What does NCSS stand for?

Tags: complexity-theory, code-metrics

I've been looking for ways to measure the complexity of my projects's source code, and have frequently come across the acronym "NCSS".  There doesn't seem to be any clear, easy-to-find definition of what it stands for.

As far as I can infer, it has something to do with [cyclomatic code complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity).

One of the places I saw "NCSS", is in the JavaNCSS tool: http://javancss.codehaus.org/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer myself, and on the JavaNCSS page too:  It stands for "Non Commenting Source Statements"